# Error while implementing Firebase Phone Auth OTP

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Firebase Phone Verification.

The project uses some other Firebase features for years and everything was OK until today. The code is standard as in all the examples available on the net.

1. I have enabled phone verification in the Firebase console.
2. SHA-1 and SHA-256 signatures are added to the console.
3. Play Integrity API enabled (not necessary I guess).
4. Test phone numbers work correctly.
5. The file "google-services.json" is part of the project for years.
6. Firebase-auth and firebase-bom dependencies added to the project of course.
7. I have checked my API key isn't restricted in the Google play console.

Log:

```
2023-05-13 19:17:38.646 E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_ID ]]- calling backend without app verification
2023-05-13 19:17:38.849 E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
2023-05-13 19:17:38.849 E/onVerificationFailed: :com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
```

The last log line is obviously called in the onVerificationFailed method of the PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() callback. Did anyone encounter such a problem?

Comment: Hey there have you been able to solve it? Somehow I'm in the same situation with test number working and all but getting the exact same error code when trying on a device

Comment: Nope... I gave up